# How to generate a EM wave with E-field parallel to the direction of propagation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I guess this is not possible in the far field. But I would like to know how to do that in the near field, say at 50cm for frequencies below 1GHz say.

Comment: You are pretty close to d.c. conditions; a calculation of the static field will give a good rough estimate of your field I guess.

Comment: take a wr770 waveguide ($7.7" \times 3.85"$) and operate it in its TM11 mode, drive it at one end and at its other open end it will radiate substantial $E_z$ component parallel with the axis of the guide.

Comment: Electrostatic waves satisfy $\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{E} = 0$, i.e., the wave vector is parallel/anti-parallel to the electric field fluctuations.  I think the biggest obstacle you will find is that these waves usually require that the fields couple to something like a plasma or charged particle oscillations.  You can generate a wave with part of $\mathbf{E}$ parallel to $\mathbf{k}$ that is EM at higher frequencies (e.g., look up X-mode in plasmas).